# Unable to setup SonarQube for python in centos 7

Tags: python, centos, sonarqube

I am trying to get SonarQube for python up and running in centos. I have downloaded this version : sonarqube-8.3.1.34397.zip.

I have installed java 11.

**java -version**

```
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.7+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.7+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**conf/wrapper.conf**

```
wrapper.java.command=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.7.10-4.el7_8.x86_64/bin/java
```

Running **./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh console** as Root user, I get following error

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:29 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:29 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:31 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:19:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Running **./bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh console** as normal user, I get following error

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:20:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
jvm 1    | 2020.07.03 00:20:45 ERROR app[][o.s.application.App] Startup failure
jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create shared memory : 
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.process.sharedmemoryfile.AllProcessesCommands.<init>(AllProcessesCommands.java:103)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.AppFileSystem.reset(AppFileSystem.java:63)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:63)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:98)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |  at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/sonarqube/temp/sharedmemory (Permission denied)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:345)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:214)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.process.sharedmemoryfile.AllProcessesCommands.<init>(AllProcessesCommands.java:100)
jvm 1    |  ... 9 common frames omitted
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Output of sonar.log file

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11 to run
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11 to run
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)
    at org.sonar.application.App.checkJavaVersion(App.java:94)
    at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:57)
    at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11 to run
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11 to run
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)
    at org.sonar.application.App.checkJavaVersion(App.java:94)
    at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:57)
    at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.07.02 23:40:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2020.07.02 23:40:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.07.02 23:40:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2020.07.02 23:40:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020.07.02 23:40:35 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2020.07.02 23:40:35 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2020.07.02 23:40:38 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.07.02 23:40:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.07.02 23:40:38 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.07.02 23:57:56 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2020.07.02 23:57:56 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.07.02 23:57:56 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2020.07.02 23:57:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020.07.02 23:57:57 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2020.07.02 23:57:57 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2020.07.02 23:58:00 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.07.02 23:58:00 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.07.02 23:58:00 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.07.03 00:08:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2020.07.03 00:08:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.07.03 00:08:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2020.07.03 00:08:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020.07.03 00:08:32 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2020.07.03 00:08:32 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2020.07.03 00:08:34 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.07.03 00:08:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.07.03 00:08:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.07.03 00:13:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2020.07.03 00:13:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.07.03 00:13:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2020.07.03 00:13:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020.07.03 00:13:23 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2020.07.03 00:13:23 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2020.07.03 00:13:25 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.07.03 00:13:25 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.07.03 00:13:25 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.07.03 00:13:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2020.07.03 00:13:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.07.03 00:13:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2020.07.03 00:13:33 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020.07.03 00:13:34 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2020.07.03 00:13:34 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2020.07.03 00:13:36 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.07.03 00:13:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.07.03 00:13:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.07.03 00:13:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2020.07.03 00:13:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.07.03 00:13:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2020.07.03 00:13:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020.07.03 00:13:48 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2020.07.03 00:13:48 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2020.07.03 00:13:50 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.07.03 00:13:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.07.03 00:13:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.07.03 00:14:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2020.07.03 00:14:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.07.03 00:14:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2020.07.03 00:14:03 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020.07.03 00:14:04 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2020.07.03 00:14:04 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2020.07.03 00:14:06 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.07.03 00:14:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.07.03 00:14:06 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2020.07.03 00:19:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2020.07.03 00:19:28 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.07.03 00:19:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2020.07.03 00:19:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
2020.07.03 00:19:29 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2020.07.03 00:19:29 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2020.07.03 00:19:31 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2020.07.03 00:19:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.07.03 00:19:31 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Answer (score 1):

For SonarQube to install from zip, you need to create a dedicated user which have access to your Java 11 installation and as well all the files of SonarQube installation directory.

Then start your SonarQube server with that user.

Do not use root user to start the SonarQube server.

Here is the link to documentation, where SonarQube has mentioned this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.3/setup/install-server/

Here is the guide to help you with Installation:

1. https://devopscube.com/setup-and-configure-sonarqube-on-linux/
2. https://docs.sonarqube.org/8.3/setup/get-started-2-minutes/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using docker and I had the same problem. I needed to include this code:

```
USER root
chmod -R 777 /opt/sonarqube
```

Then everything worked out.